# Android reload Navigation Drawer fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

There is Login option in my navigation drawer. When logged in I want it to show Logout. Navigation drawer items also have drawable left to them. Is there any I can reload/refresh/reinitialize navigation drawer once  Login has been done?

Comment: Can you please provide your code...

Answer (score 1):

You can define a Layout for your navigation area like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
   ....
    <ListView
       ...
        android:id="@+id/navigation_list"/>
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

From within your code you can now work with an `Adapter`and fill the content of your list as you wish, update works with `notifyDataSetChanged`.
For each entry of your List you can define a specific layout (with or without buttons, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

after once successful login you can get the view from adapter.

get that imageview or any other view change the image

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)getViewByPosition(pos,listview);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image);


public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make two methods for loading data into navigation drawer listview one for login and one for logout and whenever you are creating activity check your session and load listview according to that. Similarly when you are logged in then you can call the logout method from another activity and refresh the naviagtion drawer.

Comment: actually i am not able to get instance of that listview.

Comment: Thanks but i found a way